# visual studio 2015 minify "access to path bundleconfig.json denied"

Tags: visual-studio, minify, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

The issue is that when I right-click "Minify File", instead of minifying, Visual Studio gives me this error: "access to path bundleconfig.json denied".

I'm sure it is something simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was simple. All I had to do was check-out the bundleconfig.json file.

Answer (score 0):

**bundleconfig.json** should be a lock manually if it is in SVN